# I can't get this form to work either from localhost or online using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the Contact Me form that I can't get to send me an email. I am still a newbie but I don't see anything wrong. Help me out guys.

Here's the contactform controller

```
<?php
class contactform extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
     parent::__construct();
     $this->load->helper(array('form','url'));
     $this->load->library(array('session', 'form_validation', 'email'));
    }

    function index() {
     //set validation rules
     $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_alpha_space_only');
     $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Emaid ID', 'trim|required|valid_email');
     $this->form_validation->set_rules('subject', 'Subject', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
     $this->form_validation->set_rules('message', 'Message', 'trim|required|xss_clean');

     //run validation on form input
     if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        //validation fails
        //$this->load->view('contact_view');
        $this->load->view('header_view');
        $this->load->view('nav_view');
        $this->load->view('contact_view');
        $this->load->view('footer_view');
     }
     else {
        //get the form data
        $name = $this->input->post('name');
        $from_email = $this->input->post('email');
        $subject = $this->input->post('subject');
        $message = $this->input->post('message');

        //set to_email id to which you want to receive mails
        $to_email = 'mygmail@gmail.com';

        //configure email settings
        $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
        $config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';
        $config['smtp_port'] = '465';
        $config['smtp_user'] = 'mygmail@gmail.com';
        $config['smtp_pass'] = 'mypass';
        $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
        $config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
        $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
        $config['newline'] = "\r\n"; //use double quotes
        //$this->load->library('email', $config);
        $this->email->initialize($config);                        

        //send mail
        $this->email->from($from_email, $name);
        $this->email->to($to_email);
        $this->email->subject($subject);
        $this->email->message($message);
        if ($this->email->send())
        {
            // mail sent
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-success text-center">Your mail has been sent successfully!</div>');
            redirect('contactform/index');
        }
        else
        {
            //error
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">There is error in sending mail! Please try again later</div>');
            redirect('contactform/index');
        }
    }
}

 //custom validation function to accept only alphabets and space input
 function alpha_space_only($str) {
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/",$str)) {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('alpha_space_only', 'The %s field must contain only alphabets and space');
        return FALSE;
    }
    else {
        return TRUE;
    }
 }
}
?>
```

and here is my contact_view

```
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 well">
        <?php $attributes = array("class" => "form-horizontal", "name" => "contactform");
        echo form_open("contactform/index", $attributes);?>
        <fieldset>
        <legend>Contact Form</legend>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <label for="name" class="control-label">Name</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <input class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Your Full Name" type="text" value="<?php echo set_value('name'); ?>" />
                <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('name'); ?></span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <label for="email" class="control-label">Email ID</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <input class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Your Email ID" type="text" value="<?php echo set_value('email'); ?>" />
                <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('email'); ?></span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <label for="subject" class="control-label">Subject</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <input class="form-control" name="subject" placeholder="Your Subject" type="text" value="<?php echo set_value('subject'); ?>" />
                <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('subject'); ?></span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <label for="message" class="control-label">Message</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="4" placeholder="Your Message"><?php echo set_value('message'); ?></textarea>
                <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('message'); ?></span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <input name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Send" />
            </div>
        </div>
        </fieldset>
        <?php echo form_close(); ?>
        <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('msg'); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

I already checked my codes. But the problem is, I can't see why it cant send. I even tried to upload it to my website, but it still won't let me send an email.

Comment: Try to change class name. [Reference](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/styleguide.html#class-and-method-naming).

Comment: Maybe try using something like [MailTrap](http://mailtrap.io) to make sure it's not a problem with your SMTP settings. They have very simple to setup dummy mailboxes. If it's working with MailTrap and not your SMTP server you'll know it has nothing to do with your code.